# powershell: get content from ftp location / compare-object

Tags: powershell, ftp

I want a simple powershell script to get-content from a ftp location (prompt for pw) and compare contents:

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content C:\a.txt) $(Get-Content C:\b.txt)
```